# How to create a 2D int list from 1D string list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file with numbers in it, 20 numbers in each line, which looks like:

```
08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08
49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00
```

The file contains 20 lines like these, and I want to read the file and convert it into 2D int list.

I managed doing this:

```
with open(file) as f:
    t = f.read()
    t = t.split()
    t = [t[i:i+20] for i in range(20)]
```

and what I got was 2D string list, but I want them to be integers, in order to use arithmetic operations. I tried `t = [int(t[i:i+20]) for i in range(20)]` but that's not allowed since `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'`

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternate approach, using a nested list comprehension.

```
with open(fname) as f:
    t = [[int(u) for u in row.split()] for row in f]

for row in t:
    print(row)
```

---

On recent versions of Python 3, you can also use this way to create `t`, which is a little more compact, and possibly faster:

```
t = [[*map(int, row.split())] for row in f]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly recommend using `numpy` for this instead, it will be much faster

```
import numpy as np
t = np.genfromtxt(file, dtype='int32', delimiter=' ')
```

Otherwise you could read this as

```
with open(file) as f:
    t = [[int(i) for i in line.split(' ')] for line in f]
```

Comment: The delimiter you use is `' '` - will this take `'\n'` into account?

Comment: Also, `ImportError: No module named 'numpy'` :(((

Comment: The `'\n'` is the delimiter for each *row*, then the `' '` is the delimiter between each *value* for a given row.

Comment: Installed and tried it out. I get `array([ 8,  2, 22, 97, 38, 15,  0, 40,  0, 75,  4,  5,  7, 78, 52, 12, 50,
       77, 91,  8])` as the first element of t.  Is the `array` necessary?

Comment: The object you get back is indeed a `numpy.array` instead of a `list[list[int]]`. Depends what you want to do with those values. If you want to do anything like linear algebra I'd recommend using `numpy`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert each element to int, for example by using another list comprehension

```
t = [[int(ti) for ti in t[i:i+20]] for i in range(20)]
```

Comment: Thx!! that exactly what I wanted... tried doing something like that but my syntax got mixed up